# Cakephp URL rewrite and friendly url

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to rewrite cakephp default url that currently is:

```
http://localhost/cakephpproject/property/view/1
```

into this URL

```
http://localhost/cakephpproject/country/state/locality/id
```

So first i have to remove `property/view` from URL.

So far what i have done is this:

in **routes.php** file i have:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:language/property/:country/:state_province/:locality/:id', 
    array(
        'admin'=> false,
        'user'=> false, 
        'language'=>null, 
        'controller' => 'properties', 
        'action' => 'view'
    ), 
    array( 
        'pass' => array('country', 'state_province', 'locality', 'id'), 
        'persist'=>array('language'),
        'language' => '[a-z]{2}',
        'id'=>'[0-9]+',
    )
);

Router::connect(
    '/property/:country/:state_province/:locality/:id', 
    array(
        'admin'=> false,
        'user'=> false,
        'controller' => 'properties', 
        'action' => 'view'
    ), 
    array(
        'pass' => array('country' , 'state_province' , 'locality' , 'id'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

PS: I have it twice because i have a miltilingual site.

The link is this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link(
    __('View more'),
    array(
        'admin' => false,
        'user' => false,
        'controller' => 'properties',
        'action' => 'view',
        'country' => Inflector::slug($country,'-'),
        'state_province' => Inflector::slug($state_province,'-'),
        'locality'=> Inflector::slug($locality,'-'),
        'id' => $id
    ),
    array(
        'escape' => false
    )
);
?>
```

And this link generate this URL which is not the URL that i want:

```
http://localhost/biriola/properties/view/country:United-Kingdom/state_province:unknown/locality:London/id:18
```

The URL that should be generated is this:

```
http://localhost/biriola/United-Kingdom/unknown/London/18
```

I modified a bit the generated link to:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link(
    __('View more'),
    array(
        'admin' => false,
        'user' => false,
        'controller' => 'properties',
        'action' => 'view',
        Inflector::slug($country,'-'),
        Inflector::slug($state_province,'-'),
        Inflector::slug($locality,'-'),
        $id
    ),
    array(
        'escape' => false
    )
);
?>
```

And this generate the following URL:

```
http://localhost/biriola/properties/view/United-Kingdom/unknown/London/18
```

which is somehow the URL that i want but i have to remove the `properties/view/` from URL, so i don't know how to do this.

My exact CakePHP verision is: **2.5.6**

This is the full routes.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Routes configuration
 *
 * In this file, you set up routes to your controllers and their actions.
 * Routes are very important mechanism that allows you to freely connect
 * different URLs to chosen controllers and their actions (functions).
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Config
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
/**
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to controller called 'Pages',
 * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
 * to use (in this case, /app/View/Pages/home.ctp)...
 */


    $languageCodes = array('language' => 'en|it|de|es|fr|ru|zh|pt');

    Router::connect('/:language',  array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'index'), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'index'));

    Router::connect('/:language/login',  array('admin'=>false, 'user'=>false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/login', array('admin'=>false, 'user'=>false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));

    Router::connect('/:language/logout',  array('admin'=>false, 'user'=>false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/logout', array('admin'=>false, 'user'=>false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));

    Router::connect('/:language/register',  array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/register', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));

    Router::connect('/:language/faq',  array('controller' => 'faqs', 'action' => 'index'), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/faq', array('controller' => 'faqs', 'action' => 'index'));

    Router::connect('/:language/faq/question',  array('controller' => 'faqs', 'action' => 'add'), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/faq/question', array('controller' => 'faqs', 'action' => 'add'));

    Router::connect('/googlelogin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'googlelogin'));
    Router::connect('/google_login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'google_login'));

    Router::connect('/fb_login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'fb_login'));
    Router::connect('/fblogin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'fblogin'));


    /* paypal rout connect */
    Router::connect('/:language/paymentOk',  array('admin'=>false, 'user'=>false, 'controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'paymentOk'), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/paymentOk', array('admin'=>false, 'user'=>false, 'controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'paymentOk'));

    Router::connect('/:language/paymentEditOk',  array('admin'=>false, 'user'=>false, 'controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'paymentEditOk'), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/paymentEditOk', array('admin'=>false, 'user'=>false, 'controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'paymentEditOk'));

    Router::connect('/:language/paymentCancel',  array('admin'=>false, 'user'=>false, 'controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'paymentCancel'), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/paymentCancel', array('admin'=>false, 'user'=>false, 'controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'paymentCancel'));


    /*** Admin Routing URL-s */
    Router::connect('/:language/admin', array('language'=>null,'admin' => true, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'),array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/admin', array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));

    Router::connect('/:language/admin/:controller', array('language'=>null,'admin' => true, 'controller' => 'pages','action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin'), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/admin/:controller',array('admin' => true,'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin'));

    Router::connect('/:language/admin/:controller/:action/*', array('language'=>null,'admin' => true,  'controller' => 'pages','action' => null, 'prefix' => 'admin'),array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/admin/:controller/:action/*',array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'pages','action' => null, 'prefix' => 'admin'));


    /*** User Routing URL-s */
    Router::connect('/:language/user', array('language'=>null,'user' => true, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'prefix' => 'user'),array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/user', array('user' => true, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard','prefix' => 'user'));

    Router::connect('/:language/user/:controller', array('language'=>null,'user' => true, 'controller' => 'pages','action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'user'),array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/user/:controller', array('user' => true, 'controller' => 'pages','action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'user'));

    Router::connect('/:language/user/:controller/:action/*', array('language'=>null,'user' => true,  'controller' => 'pages','action' => null, 'prefix' => 'user'),array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/user/:controller/:action/*', array('user' => true,  'controller' => 'pages','action' => null, 'prefix' => 'user'));


    /* sitemap */
    Router::connect('/:language/sitemap.xml', array('language'=>null,'controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'sitemap','admin'=>false, 'user'=>false), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/sitemap.xml', array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'sitemap','admin'=>false, 'user'=>false));


    /*** Languages */
    Router::connect('/:language/:controller',array('language'=>null,'controller' => 'pages','action' => 'index'),array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/:controller',array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'index'));

    Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', array('language'=>null,'controller' => 'pages','action' => null), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*', array('controller' => 'pages','action' => null));

    /* property view url rewriting */
    Router::connect(
        '/:language/:country/:state_province/:locality/:id', 
        array(
            'admin'=> false,
            'user'=> false, 
            'language'=>null, 
            'controller' => 'properties', 
            'action' => 'view'
        ), 
        array( 
            'pass' => array('country', 'state_province', 'locality', 'id'), 
            'persist'=>array('language'),
            'language' => '[a-z]{2}',
            'id'=>'[0-9]+',
        )
    );
    Router::connect(
        '/:country/:state_province/:locality/:id', 
        array(
            'admin'=> false,
            'user'=> false,
            'controller' => 'properties', 
            'action' => 'view'
        ), 
        array(
            'pass' => array('country' , 'state_province' , 'locality' , 'id'),
            'id' => '[0-9]+'
        )
    );


    /**
    * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
    */
    Router::connect('/:language/pages/*', array('language'=>null,'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'), array('language' => '[a-z]{2}','persist'=>array('language')));
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));


/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
    CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please tag your question only with the tag that actually fits the version that you are using. Also please always additionally mention your _exact_ CakePHP version!

Comment: @ndm  I edited the question and my cakephp verision is 2.5.6.

Comment: Do you have any more routes in your configuration placed _before_ the routes that you are showing here? If so, please add them to your question.

Comment: @ndm i added all the routes that i have at routes.php file. look at the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

### Order matters

The

```
Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*', array('controller' => 'pages','action' => null));
```

route is a catch-all for all URLs in `/abc/xyz/*` format, and since order matters (top to bottom) when matching/reverse-routing, it steals your reverse routing attempts, and thus spits out such a URL with named (`key:value`) elements, as the catching route doesn't have any of these parameters defined.

So, move your new routes above that one, and then use the first `link()` call variant, that's the correct one.

### Redundant default values, they are just confusing

Also note that routes like this doesn't make much sense, this will never result in a URL like `/controller/action/xyz` being routed to the `Pages` controller, unless the controller name in the URL is `pages`, and for reverse routing it will only match for the pages controller, resulting in URLs like `/pages/action/xyz`, making the use of the `:controller` placeholder redundant.

The default values are redundant and confusing.

I'd suggest that you carefully study the docs on routing, then check your routes and remove the redundant default values.

See **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html**

Comment: thanks for you answer, i tried to do what you said, i even deleted all the routs and i kept only the cakephp initial routes, and i added the new routes just for testing purposes, and still it didn't work, i mean it it still generate the same key:value parameters in URL.
`http://localhost/biriola/properties/view/country:France/state_province:unknown/locality:unknown/id:13`
any halp would be very appreciated.

Comment: @Johnny Well, there's not much I can do from here, you'll have to debug this further on your own, as the route and the link call that you are showing are working just fine for me as is, and right now the only problem I can think of are the mentioned conflicting routes. I'd suggest to try it with a fresh, recent CakePHP installation and check whether the problem still occurs.